Serge Lang's Definition of kernel in abelian category
In Serge Lang's Algebra, page 133, he defines kernel of morphism in an abelian category using exact sequence.

Then we say that $\mathfrak{A}$ is an additive category. Given a morphism $E \xrightarrow[]{f} F$ in $\mathfrak{A}$, we define a kernel of $f$ to be a morphism $E' \to E$ such that for all objects $X$ in the category, the following sequence is exact: $$0 \to \operatorname{Mor}(X,E') \to \operatorname{Mor}(X,E) \to \operatorname{Mor}(X,F).$$ We define a cokernel for $f$ to be a morphism $F \to F''$ such that for all objects $X$ in the category, the following sequence is exact: $$0 \to \operatorname{Mor}(F'',X) \to \operatorname{Mor} (F,X) \to \operatorname{Mor}(E,X).$$ It is immediately verified that kernels and cokernels are universal in a suitable category, and hence uniquely determined up to a unique isomorphism if they exist.

Then how do we define exact sequence in an abelian category without using kernel? I know he is mainly discussing theorems using language of modules, but regardless of it, I think it is a circular logic. Am I missing something important?

The sequence of morphism groups in the definition lives in the category of abelian groups, not in the additive category $\mathcal{A}$.
The presumption is that you already understand the notions of kernel and exact sequence for abelian groups.
This definition suggests an exercise, which you should solve: Prove that, when we view the category of abelian groups as an additive category in the natural way, Lang's definition of kernel and cokernel agree (up to isomorphism) with their standard definitions for abelian groups.
